# PowerBI - Calculate last week data with current week

Tags: excel-formula, powerbi, powerquery

Hi I have following data

```
+-----------------------------------+
|WEEK              |REVENUE         |
+-----------------------------------+
|03/09/2020        |$1000           |
+-----------------------------------+
|03/16/2020        |$900            |
+-----------------------------------+
|03/23/2020        |$1050           |
+-----------------------------------+
```

The output I need is revenue from last week ($1050) divided by revenue from the week before ($900) i.e **1050 / 900 - 1 = 0.166**

**OutPut**

```
+-----------------------------------+
|WEEK              |REV WoW%        |
+-----------------------------------+
|03/23/2020        |17%             |
+-----------------------------------+
```

The formula written by me is as below

```
Rev WoW% = 
IF(
    ISFILTERED('2020 Data'[Week]),
    VAR __PREV_WEEK =
        CALCULATE(
            SUM('2020 Data'[Revenue]),
            DATEADD('2020 Data'[Week].[Date], -7, DAY)
        )
    RETURN
        DIVIDE(SUM('2020 Data'[Revenue]) - __PREV_WEEK, __PREV_WEEK)
)
```

Currently using the above formula, I am getting 0% whereas I should be getting 17%. Please help me correct this.

Answer (score 0):

Screenshot with your desired Result

[image]

I first created Calcualted Column as Previous with below expression

```
Previous = var PreviousDate = MAXX(FILTER(ALL('Table');EARLIER('Table'[Week].[Date]) >'Table'[Week].[Date]);'Table'[Week].[Date])

Return CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[Revenue]);FILTER('Table';'Table'[Week].[Date]=PreviousDate))
```

Then I created another calculated column as Output with belw expression, it is based on previous column

```
Output = If(ISBLANK('Table'[Previous]);
0;
'Table'[Revenue]/'Table'[Previous]-1)
```

In addition to show output as Percentage Column please Go to your Table, Particular Column, in this case Output and make it to percentage, below screenshot for ref

[image]

Comment: You are creating Measure hence the error, you need to create calculated column.